# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'base') Getting this error in next.js when I switched to turbopack

Tags: mongoose, next.js, turbopack

I am using next14 app router and routes handlers with mongoose ORM. It was working fine when i was using webpack.
here is the stacktrace

```
⨯ TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'base')
    at new Mongoose (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_mongoose_lib_4acd6e._.js:14985:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_mongoose_lib_4acd6e._.js:15967:49)
    at [project]/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js [app-rsc] (ecmascript) (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_mongoose_lib_4acd6e._.js:15971:3)
    at instantiateModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:490:23)
    at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:541:12)
    at commonJsRequire (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:127:20)    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_mongoose_d0f576._.js:13:18)
    at [project]/node_modules/mongoose/index.js [app-rsc] (ecmascript) (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_mongoose_d0f576._.js:65:3)
    at instantiateModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:490:23)
    at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:541:12)
    at esmImport (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:113:20)      
    at C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\_8d5391._.js:14:137
    at [project]/src/middleware/mongo.ts [app-rsc] (ecmascript) (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\_8d5391._.js:50:3)
    at instantiateModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:490:23)
    at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:541:12)
    at esmImport (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:113:20)      
    at C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\_8d5391._.js:57:130
    at [project]/src/app/api/pranit/route.ts [app-rsc] (ecmascript) (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\_8d5391._.js:67:3)
    at instantiateModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:490:23)
    at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:541:12)
    at esmImport (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:113:20)      
    at C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_next_dist_d8f9c1._.js:2685:140    
    at [project]/node_modules/next/dist/esm/build/templates/app-route.js/(INNER_APP_ROUTE)/[project]/src/app/api/pranit/route.ts [app-rsc] (ecmascript) (ecmascript) (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\node_modules_next_dist_d8f9c1._.js:2720:3)
    at instantiateModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:490:23)
    at instantiateRuntimeModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:549:12)
    at Object.getOrInstantiateRuntimeModule (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\chunks\[turbopack]_runtime.js:564:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\.next\server\app\api\pranit\route.js:17:26)    
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at mod.require (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)  
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at requirePage (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:109:84)      
    at C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:59:84
    at async loadComponentsImpl (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:59:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (C:\Users\PRANIT\DATA\Programmer Pranit\pranitpatil\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:671:36) {
  page: '/api/pranit'
}
```

I switched to webpack(default) and it is working fine. Is there any other fix?